Определить что между хостом и гет параметрами слеш
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\..+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

Не понимаю, как читается данное правило?
Если url http://www.site.ru/, значит переадресуем на страницу https://site.ru/
Собственно как так прописать, что переадресовываем со слешем при условии что есть гет параметры. Если нет, переадресовываем на url в конце которого не будет слеша.
